# Rolling RecycleView to top position in android on button click

Tags: android, xml, android-recyclerview

I am making an application which consist of **recyclerView** in it, I have implemented it successfully, now what I 
 want is that if I place a button on toolbar for **rolling back to top of item in recycleView** and when I click that button my RecyclerView rolls to **top item** or the **first item** which is present in my **recycleView list**, I have researched many questions but did not found any useful solution to my problem. please help

> I am using Android Studio.
>
> and the RecyclerView is also **reversed** using

```
layout.setReverseLayout(true)
layout.setStackFromEnd(true);
```

> so that if a new post comes it
>   will be shown on top rather than bottom

Answer (score 0):

You should use a `.smoothScrollToPosition` to scroll smoothly to the desired position.

If your problem is that you want the scroll to position to be on the actual top of the new view of the List. You should create a custom LinearLayoutManager which uses a custom `LinearSmoothScroller` which overrides: `override fun getVerticalSnapPreference(): Int = SNAP_TO_START`

When you have done this override the `.smoothScrollToPosition` to use this new custom smooth scroller

Answer (score 0):

The below code will first check whether the view is scrolled or not and will change the visibility of the button accordingly:

```
MyRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
        super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
        int visibility = (MyLayoutManager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition() != 0) ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE;
        btn.setVisibility(visibility);
    }
});
```